# Querying one record of each type between dates

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.2

I have a table (attendance) like this

```
+----+--------------------------+-------+------------+
| id |         employeeId       | type  |    date    |
+----+--------------------------+-------+------------+
|  0 | alberto                  |  A    | 2019-10-01 |
|  1 | alberto                  |  A    | 2019-10-02 |
|  2 | alberto                  |  A    | 2019-10-03 |
|  3 | pedro                    |  B    | 2019-10-01 |
|  4 | pedro                    |  B    | 2019-10-02 |
|  5 | pedro                    |  B    | 2019-10-03 |
|  6 | juan                     |  A    | 2019-10-01 |
|  7 | juan                     |  A    | 2019-10-02 |
|  8 | oscar                    |  A    | 2019-10-01 |
|  9 | marcelo                  |  B    | 2019-10-01 |
| 10 | marcelo                  |  B    | 2019-10-02 |
| 11 | marcelo                  |  B    | 2019-10-03 |
+----+--------------------------+-------+------------+
```

Using a LINQ expression and given a date range for example 2019-10-01 to 2019-10-03, I want to find the first employeeId of each type that has a record on each of the dates between the range meaning one record for 2019-10-01, another for 2019-10-02 and another for 2019-10-03, so the result should be

```
alberto   |    typeA
pedro     |    TypeB
```

So far I have this:

```
_context.Attendance
     .Where(s => s.Date>= sm.InitialDate && s.Fecha <= sm.FinalDate)
```

I have tried a few things but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a good start, after filtering out the elements outside the date range, you should group by the type, then get the first one in each group:

```
var list = _context.Attendance
    .Where(s => s.Date>= sm.InitialDate && s.Fecha <= sm.FinalDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .Select(x => new { x.EmployeeId, x.Type })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I make sure that exists one record for each day of the range dates?

Comment: @albertolo how’s that relevant to your question?

Comment: I probably did not include that in the question, I put it on the details after the table.